# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1e6'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read excel contains more than one million rows with the below code:

```
excel_df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), excel), sheet_name='SHO', header = 1)
```

and I found the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/haroo501/PycharmProjects/My_Check_Missing_Relation_Tool/Data_Types_Test.py", line 6, in <module>
    excel_df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), excel))
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\My_Missing_Relation_tool\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\My_Missing_Relation_tool\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 821, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\My_Missing_Relation_tool\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\My_Missing_Relation_tool\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\My_Missing_Relation_tool\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 36, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\My_Missing_Relation_tool\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 130, in open_workbook
    bk = xlsx.open_workbook_2007_xml(
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\My_Missing_Relation_tool\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 841, in open_workbook_2007_xml
    x12sheet.process_stream(zflo, heading)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\My_Missing_Relation_tool\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 550, in own_process_stream
    self_do_row(elem)
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\My_Missing_Relation_tool\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 635, in do_row
    self.rowx = int(row_number) - 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1e6'
```

any idea how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured when I convert it from `xlsx` type to `csv` type it works due to the large of data

- First Step: Convert the `xlsx` to `csv`
- Second Step: instead `df.read_excel` make `df.read_csv`...

It was solved like this

Answer (score 1):

**This will help in displaying possible non-compatible data:**

```
 excel_data = pandas.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name='sheet1')
 excel_data.to_csv(csv_file_path)

 csv_data = pandas.read_csv(csv_path)
 print(csv_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, and found out that is due to a special formatting of the row index in the Excel file. In my case the file is automatically generated by an external service.

I'm using the `openpyxl` library and you seem to be using the `xlrd` one (which, by the way, is not maintained anymore and [the author suggests](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) to use `openpyxl` if you are only dealing with `.xlsx` files), but the issue is the same.
You have to modify the file "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\My_Missing_Relation_tool\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 635, from:

`self.rowx = int(row_number) - 1`

to:

`self.rowx = int(float(row_number)) - 1`

This because the builtin function `int()` does not support strings representing numbers written in scientific such as `1e6` (from you error trace, and which translates to 1.000.000), and we then first have to use `float()` to transform the string into a valid float, and then convert it to an integer.

I submitted the issue for the `openpyxl` library here: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1557